# C++/CLI, static constructor outside class declaration

Tags: static, constructor, c++-cli

How do I put body of static constructor of a managed class outside class declaration? This syntax seems to be compilable, but does it really mean static constructor, or just a static (=not visible outside translation unit) function?

```
ref class Foo {
    static Foo();
}

static Foo::Foo() {}
```

Comment: This might help you : 
http://www.drdobbs.com/184401941

Comment: fingerprint211b: seen that. This article describes how does it work, but they don't mention this specific usage.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct syntax to create a C++/CLI static constructor.  You can know its not creating a static function since that is not a valid function declaration syntax.  Functions must have the return type specified.  Also, the compiler would complain that `Foo()` is not a member of class Foo if it weren't linking it to the constructor you declared in the class definition.

You can test the fairly easily:

```
using namespace System;

ref class Foo {
    static Foo();
    Foo();
}

static Foo::Foo() { Console.WriteLine("Static Constructor"); }
Foo::Foo() { Console.WriteLine("Constructor"); }

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Foo ^f = gcnew Foo();
    Console.WriteLine("Main");
}
```

This would output:

> Static Constructor
>   Constructor
>   Main

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was getting an error because of that syntax, then I noticed it was because of something unrelated to static contructor.